# Clear ng-model then Update ng-model with new value

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Angular and Ionic Application

I have a form that has a lot of `<select>` elements, The form offers the user to select from a list or `if the <option> = 'Other' then I show another <input>` to enter the value. I then save the value to another `ng-model`.

```
 <select data-ng-model="minor.tests.liveEarth"
                name="minorTestLiveEarth"
                required>
          <option></option>
          <option>>200</option>
          <option>>299</option>
          <option>>500</option>
          <option>>1000</option>
          <option>Other</option>
        </select>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label" ng-show="minor.tests.liveEarth === 'Other'">
        <span class="input-label">Please Specify</span>
        <input type="text"
               placeholder="live earth other"
               ng-maxlength="10"
               data-ng-model="minor.tests.liveEarthOther"
               name="minorTestLiveEarthOther">
      </label>
```

I originally used `<datalist>` but doesn't show up on iOS.

I assigned the `liveEarthOther` to the same as the `<select>` liveEarth but it has `'Other'` assigned to the ng-model, which then the user has to delete the input value `Other` before entering their value.

I have looked for a combobox kind of control but haven't found one that works properly.

How could I make this into a directive or any thing suitable that could perform the renaming without the user having to delete the value.

I want to use this functionality many times in the application I am building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have overcomplicated things by re-using the ngModel. If you change the value `minor.tests.liveEarth` you'll mess up your select because anything other than the given values will cause nothing to be selected. But if you *don't* change `minor.tests.liveEarth` then you'll have to delete it when the user fills in the text input. This would then *also* mess up the select box!

What I would do is record the value of the text input to a different variable. Keep the `ng-show="minor.tests.liveEarth === 'Other'"` as it is, but change your input to

```
<input type="text" 
    placeholder="Fill in your other live earth"
    ng-maxlength="10"
    data-ng-model="tempVar" />
```

This way the input will be still be recorded, but the select won't be messed up on the ngModel change. Due to the `placeholder`, the user will know that they have to fill in the text box.

In your js, you'll have to create a validating function when the form is submitted along the lines of:

```
var validateLiveEarth = function(){
  if(minor.tests.liveEarth === "Other"){
    //check that tempVar meets validation
    //assign tempVar to whatever form you're sending
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help this has given me a way to validate and assign my model.